# Check the missing integers from a range in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, range

Given a building infos dataframe as follows:

```
    id  floor     type
0    1     13   office
1    2     12   office
2    3      9   office
3    4      9   office
4    5      7   office
5    6      6   office
6    7      9   office
7    8      5   office
8    9      5   office
9   10      5   office
10  11      4   retail
11  12      3   retail
12  13      2   retail
13  14      1   retail
14  15     -1  parking
15  16     -2  parking
16  17     13   office
```

I want to check if in the column `floor`, there are missing floors (**except for floor 0, which is by default not existing**).

Code:

```
set(df['floor'])
```

Out:

```
{-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 12, 13}
```

For example, for the dataset above (`-2, -1, 1, 2, ..., 13`), I want to return an indication **floor 8, 10, 11 are missing in your dataset**. Otherwise, just returns **no missing floor in your dataset**.

How could I do that in Pandas or Numpy? Thanks a lot for your help at advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) for difference with range created `np.arange` and omitted `0`:

```
arr = np.arange(df['floor'].min(), df['floor'].max() + 1)
arr = arr[arr != 0]

out = np.setdiff1d(arr, df['floor'])

out = ('no missing floor in your dataset' 
       if len(out) == 0 
       else f'floor(s) {", ".join(out.astype(str))} are missing in your dataset')
print (out)
floor(s) 8, 10, 11 are missing in your dataset
```

Comment: Thanks, if I want automaticly get range values from column `floor`?

Comment: @ahbon That is [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html#numpy.arange) not `np.arrange`

Comment: Yes, I notice that. :)